# KafkaJS: Commit the whole batch

Tags: kafkajs

I'm having trouble committing the whole batch at once processing it. In the docs I see [an example where they resolve the offset of a single message from the batch after processing it](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming#a-name-each-batch-a-eachbatch), I need to resolve the offset or commit them, *after* processing all of the messages in the batch.

Can I do this with the built-in `eachBatchAutoResolve`? Do I need anything else like `resolveOffset`, or is that it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Use `eachBatchAutoResolve`. If I understood the docs correctly, if `storePoints()` throw, it won't commit. And the

```js
await this.redpandaConsumer.run({
  eachBatch: async ({ batch, heartbeat, isRunning, isStale }) => {
    const points: Points[] = [];
    for (const message of batch.messages) {
      if (!isRunning() || isStale()) break;

      points.push(message);
      await heartbeat(); // not sure if needed here
    }
    await this.storePoints(points); // throws if it fails
    await heartbeat();
  },
  eachBatchAutoResolve: true,
});
```